# C language not giving me the output in decimals

Tags: c, temperature

```
//Converts Farenheit tempretaure to into the celsius scale

#include <stdio.h>
#define FREEZING_PT 32.0f
#define FACTOR 5.0f/9.0f

int main(void)
{
    float faren,c;

    printf("Enter the Farenheit temperature: ");
    scanf("%f",&faren);
    float c = (faren - FREEZING_PT)*FACTOR;

    printf("The required celsius tempreature is: %.1f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Im a Complete C beginner and this may be very elementary but I cannot figure out the problem here.

In the above code, the value I get returned is always the Celsius temperature in integer values, even if it is a float type. For example, if the Fahrenheit temperature was 0°, the result in Celsius should be -17.7°, but I get the result only as -17°.

Edited code:

```
//Converts Farenheit tempretaure to into the celsius scale

#include <stdio.h>
#define FREEZING_PT 32.0f
#define FACTOR 5.0f/9.0f

int main(void)
{
    float faren,c;

    printf("Enter the Farenheit temperature: ");
    scanf("%f",&faren);
    c = (faren - FREEZING_PT)*FACTOR;

    printf("The required celsius tempreature is: %.1f\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've declared `c` two times. First one here: `float faren,c;`, the second one here: `float c = (faren - FREEZING_PT)*FACTOR;`. Remove the `float` from `float c = (faren - FREEZING_PT)*FACTOR;`

Comment: Your code shoudln't even compile since you declare `c` twice. Is this an issue with you actual program or did this happen while you were copying the code to the question?

Comment: I've removed it, and it makes no difference to the output?

Comment: "the result in Celsius should be -17.7°," -->more like -17.8.

Comment: Some advice for a complete beginner: Avoid using macros for now. ie. don't use `#define`

Comment: @Elliott alright ill keep that in mind

Comment: @MrKhonsu suppose you would do the reverse by **dividing** by `FACTOR` that would substitute out *textually to* `c/5.0f/9.0f` instead of correct `c/(5.0f/9.0f)`, because your macro value was not parenthesized. In any case, you must have had a left-over program using `int` and the new program failed to compile hence you running the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you've declared the variable 'c'  twice. After removing the first declaration of the variable 'c', it's working properly.

I'm getting the correct output.

> Enter the Farenheit temperature: 0
>
> The required celsius tempreature is: -17.8
>
> Enter the Farenheit temperature: 1
>
> The required celsius tempreature is: -17.2
>
> Enter the Farenheit temperature: 2
>
> The required celsius tempreature is: -16.7

Remove the first declaration of the variable 'c'. It should work.

Comment: yes it does, it was a trivial mistake on my part